# (java)should/how I refactor this code?

Tags: java, refactoring

I am working on a old application with n-tier architecture. I have a domain service like this:

```
public Class DomainServiceA{

     //inject
     private ObjectADao adao;
     private ParamDao pdao;
     //others dao needed

     public List<DomainObjectA> getListDomainA(){
          List<DtoA> listDto = adao.getListaDto();
          Param someparam = pdao.getParamA();
          //some code to change listDto to listDomainObject
          return listDomainObject;
     }

     //some ohters services methodes

}
```

for testing this methode, I need to mock the DAO and the methode used in this methode. I want to refactor this code

```
public Class DomainServiceA{

     public List<DomainObjectA> getListDomainA(Supplier<List<DtoA>> listDto, Param someparam){
          //some code to change listDto to listDomainObject
          return listDomainObject;
     }

     //some ohters services methodes

}
```

So I dont need mock the daos anymore, and I think it increase testablity and readability. but for calling this method/service, the presentation layer must call the persistence layer to build the supplier. This is bad, right? Should I not refactor the code, and test with mock?

Comment: @ilumin these kind of questions should not be asked here

Comment: Yes, you should not refactor the code, it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your refactor in this way, it means that the `DomainServiceA`  is not a service any longer but a mapper that map a List of DTO to a List of domain objects because you pass  DTOs in the method and you return domain objects in.
It changes the overall intention of the method.
It is not `getListDomainA()` but `toListDomain()`.

> So I dont need mock the daos anymore, and I think it increase
>   testablity and readability. but for calling this method/service

The logic of the invoked DAO is still present but it is on the above layer and you should also test it. So **it just moves the issue somewhere else** and **makes your design unclear** : presentation layer should not communicate with repository layer as a service layer exists but it does.

Mocking DAO/repositories is a normal thing and you want to mock them to test the core logic of the service calling it and also to make sure that the method is invoked as it should be.
If you want to focus unit tests on the DTO-domain mapping you could  introduce a Mapper class that accepts the DTO List and make the service call it. In this way no mock is required to test the Mapper class.